# Hadoop analyze two file with different structure

Tags: hadoop, hive

How could i analyze two file with different structure in hadoop (with out MapReduce)?

Ex: File 1 is csv have O2 index in third column

File 2 is csv have O2 index in second column

I know that i can use MapReduce for manually analyze but is that anyway more automatically? Because of it not just two file. May be more!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could store the two files in separate locations, build two separate hive tables and then combine the two tables into one view...

This will most likely be fairly inefficient and should probably be done using custom Map/ Reduce.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Moll, in my case, may be i have to pre-proccess data before store in to hdfs